# Increasing chassis fan speeds?

Tags: hardware, bios, fan, cooling

I have a rack-type server whose motherboard is ASUS Z11PG-D16 Series (according to lshw).

`ipmitool` reports 7 front fans, and I would like to increase their speeds.

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Heat up the server by doing some work with it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I hope you are joking.. I want to increase the fan speeds because the fans don't cool the GPUs enough even when they are overheated.

Comment: Exactly what is this server comprised of, then?

Comment: If your hardware does support software control the following provides some instructions https://askubuntu.com/q/22108/797924

Comment: It turned out that this model has fan control on its IPMI GUI. But thanks for your comments.